# Problems with xelatex and arc in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

When I use `\setdefaultlanguage{thai}` and `arc` command, output not smooth. How to set my XeLaTeX code? I think this ploblem about thai scale, or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}{Microsoft Sans Serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc (-120:175:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It’s just getting ridiculous with `\draw (0,0) arc (-120:175:1);`. Oh, and it works with the current CVS version of TikZ, so it seems like it is/will be fixed.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I don't think so, if I use your command (not specific unit), its very haywire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of workarounds I found. Do not set the default language to `thai` and just use `\thaifont` whenever you need Thai characters. Usually we don't need that many Thai strings in this kind of image anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}{Microsoft Sans Serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc (-120:175:1cm);
\node at (2,2) {\thaifont โรงเรียน};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the great advice. I have new idea for this problem: Add another font (englishfont) in premble  `\setotherlanguage{english}` and `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Microsoft Sans Serif}` and use `{\englishfont \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikpicture} }